# Making maxSession property configurable for a specific MDB in JBoss EAP 5.1

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jboss6.x, message-driven-bean

How to make maxSession value for an MDB user-configurable?

There is an MDB that listens for a message from a specific queue. It is defined as an annotation.

`@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "5")`.

In order to change the value of the maxSession, the code has to be compiled everytime.

Is there a way to make it user configurable so that there is no build required and without restarting jboss?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to externalize this setting from ear:

https://community.jboss.org/thread/178162

But restart is still required.

**Update**

Found [a way](https://community.jboss.org/message/726025#726025) to apply new maxSession with system property reference in `ejb-jar.xml`:

```
<activation-config-property>
   <activation-config-property-name>maxSession</activation-config-property-name>
   <activation-config-property-value>${my.mdb.maxSession:30}</activation-config-property-value>
</activation-config-property>
```

Full JBoss restart is not required, only ear redeploy is needed in this case.

It works for all JBoss versions [until](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3816) JBoss AS 7.

Note that maxSession must be in sync with max pool size:
https://community.jboss.org/message/549083#549083

Comment: System property expansion support was reintroduced since JBoss AS 7.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Note as well, that both the number of sessions and the instance pool size can be specified in an AOP configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aop xmlns="urn:jboss:aop-beans:1.0">
   <domain name="IBMMQ Message Driven Bean" extends="Message Driven Bean" inheritBindings="true">
      <annotation expr="class(*)">
          @org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool (value="StrictMaxPool", maxSize=10, timeout=10000)
      </annotation>
      <annotation expr="!class(@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.DefaultActivationSpecs)">
         @org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.DefaultActivationSpecs (value={@javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "channel", propertyValue = "SSL.CLIENTS"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "queueManager", propertyValue = "SSLQM"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName", propertyValue = "10.0.0.124"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port", propertyValue = "1415"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transportType", propertyValue = "CLIENT"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "sslCipherSuite", propertyValue = "SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA")})
      </annotation>
   </domain>
</aop>
```

You then add the annotation:

```
@AspectDomain("IBMMQ Message Driven Bean")
```

to your MDB.  This is can be used to externalize both the number of seesions and the instance pool size.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [how many Message Driven Beans are created in Jboss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469271/how-many-message-driven-beans-are-created-in-jboss) maxSession can't exceed the setting of StrictMaxPool. So when tweaking maxSession - this setting need to be changed as well!