# how many Message Driven Beans are created in Jboss?

Tags: jboss, ejb, jboss-mdb

*JBoss: 6 or 7*

**Question1:**

How many instances of Message Driven Bean are created by *Jboss* to handle messages?

**Question2:**

How to configure number of Message Driven Beans created by *JBoss*?

Answer (score 5):

According to this JBoss EAP 5 (JBoss AS 6) documentation:

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/sect-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Message_Driven_Beans.html

You need to take care of two concepts

1. Pool Size: This pool is named StrictMaxPool and the default values is 15. It must be configurated on JBoss config files (read link)
2. Session Size: This is the parameter configured according to the standard with the following annotations:

   ```
   @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="minSessions"
   , propertyValue="25")
   @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="maxSessions"
   , propertyValue="50")
   ```

Where minSession and maxSessions are the number of instances created by JBoss. **But if the StrictMaxPool is set to 15 then you cannot create more than 15 instances although you configure maxSessions to 50**

For JBoss EAP 6 (JBoss AS 7) the pool is named *mdb-strict-max-pool* and their default max pool size is 20.